# R and dplyr: group by value ranges

Tags: r, dplyr

hi everyone I have a dataframe like this:

```
    value     count
    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1         10
 2     2         20
 3     3         30
 4     4         40
 5     5         50
 6     6         60
```

I would like to be able to divide my observations into intervals. The first and last interval must include all the observations left out of the range (for example of 2)

```
      interval     count
         <???>     <dbl>
 1     [<1, 2]        30
 2      [3, 4]        50
 3     [5, >6]       110
```

Is it possible to do this with dplyr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cut()` to create a grouping variable with which to summarise count.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = cut(value, c(-Inf, 2, 4, Inf))) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(count))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  grp      count
  <fct>    <int>
1 (-Inf,2]    30
2 (2,4]       70
3 (4, Inf]   110
```